there is a problem with my luhn checksum in cs50 that I can't figure out
this the cs50 problem in question :
credit
the logic in my checksum seem to be ill constructed as it doesn't recognize 4222222222222 as valid even though it sums is 40 and falsely indicates
4111111111111113 as visa even though it sums is 28
other than these two it labels any other credit card correctly
this is my code :
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool digit(string str, int buffer);
int numofdigits(long long card_num);
int fst_ndigit(long long credit, int buffer, int numdigit);

int main(void)
{

    long long credit = get_long("please enter your credit card number :  ");

    //Note:
    //using a boolean variable can reduce repetition of " INVALID " message
    bool valid = true;
    if (credit < (long long) pow(10, 13) || credit > (long long) pow(10, 16))
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        valid = false;
    }


    int buffer = numofdigits(credit);

    long long aux = credit;
    int last_two;
    int last_one;
    //Note: variable names cannot start with numbers!
    int secondlast_one;
    int mul = 1;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    if(valid){
    for(int i = 0; aux > 0; i++)
    {
        //1st step :
        //Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit,
        //and then add those products’ digits together.

        last_two = aux % (long long) pow(10, buffer-2);
        last_one = last_two % 10;
        secondlast_one = last_two / 10;
        mul = secondlast_one*2;

        if((mul / 10) != 0)
        {
            sum1 += (mul / 10) + (mul % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            sum1 += mul;
        }
        //2nd step:
        //Add the previous sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
        sum2 += last_one;

        aux = aux / 100;
    }

    //3rd step:
    //If the total’s last digit is 0
    //(or, put more formally, if the total modulo 10 is congruent to 0),
    //the number is valid!
    if((sum1 + sum2) % 10 ==0)
    {
        valid = true;
    }


    int fst_two = fst_ndigit(credit, buffer, 2);
    int fst_one = fst_ndigit(credit, buffer, 1);

    char str[17];
    // Note :
    // sprintf(str, "%d", (int)credit);
    // this line is incorrect because the prog will spit out a random integer

    sprintf(str, "%lld", credit);
    // lld is format for long long int


    if (digit(str, buffer) && valid)
    {
        if (buffer == 15 && (fst_two == 34 || fst_two == 37))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        else if (buffer == 16 && (fst_two == 51 || fst_two == 52 || fst_two == 53 || fst_two == 54 || fst_two == 55))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        else if ((buffer == 13 || buffer == 16) && fst_one == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    }

}


int numofdigits(long long card_num)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (card_num > 0)
    {
        card_num /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

bool digit(string str, int buffer)
{
    bool all_digits = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            all_digits = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return all_digits;
}

int fst_ndigit(long long credit, int buffer, int numdigit)
{
    int fstndigit = (int) (credit / (long long) pow(10, buffer - numdigit));
    return fstndigit;
}

as you see in the checksum section:
int buffer = numofdigits(credit);

    long long aux = credit;
    int last_two;
    int last_one;
    //Note: variable names cannot start with numbers!
    int secondlast_one;
    int mul = 1;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    if(valid){
    for(int i = 0; aux > 0; i++)
    {
        //1st step :
        //Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit,
        //and then add those products’ digits together.

        last_two = aux % (long long) pow(10, buffer-2);
        last_one = last_two % 10;
        secondlast_one = last_two / 10;
        mul = secondlast_one*2;

        if((mul / 10) != 0)
        {
            sum1 += (mul / 10) + (mul % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            sum1 += mul;
        }
        //2nd step:
        //Add the previous sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
        sum2 += last_one;

        aux = aux / 100;
    }

    //3rd step:
    //If the total’s last digit is 0
    //(or, put more formally, if the total modulo 10 is congruent to 0),
    //the number is valid!
    if((sum1 + sum2) % 10 ==0)
    {
        valid = true;
    }

in a loop that goes on until all digits of the credit card number is checked, I tried to extract the last digit and the second to last then multiplied the latter by 2 and added to sum1 and if it surpasses 9, I add each of its digits indiviually then sum2 is the sum of every other digit beginnig with the last digit
finally out of the loop:
if total = sum1 + sum2 have as last digit 0 then the credit car number is valid other than that invalid
can someone please help me ?
edit:
int buffer = numofdigits(credit);
    char str[17];
    // Note :
    // sprintf(str, "%d", (int)credit);
    // this line is incorrect because the prog will spit out a random integer

    sprintf(str, "%lld", credit);
    // lld is format for long long int

    int sum = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i;

  // Iterate through the digits from right to left
  for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int digit = str[i] - '0';

    // Double every second digit
    if ((len - i) % 2 == 0) {
      digit *= 2;

      // Subtract 9 if the doubled digit is greater than 9
      if (digit > 9) {
        digit -= 9;
      }
    }

    sum += digit;
  }
  int checksum = sum % 10;
  valid = (checksum == 0);

still the same problem
2nd edit :
this is the code i wrote that passed the cs50 check
Thank everyone for your input.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool digit(string str, int buffer);
int numofdigits(long int credit);
int fst_ndigit(long int credit, int buffer, int numdigit);
bool checksum(long int credit);

int main(void)
{
    long int credit = get_long("please enter your credit card number :  ");

    bool valid = true;

    if (credit < (long long) pow(10, 12) || credit > (long long) pow(10, 17))
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (valid)
    {
        valid = checksum(credit);
        if (valid)
        {
            int buffer = numofdigits(credit);
            int fst_two = fst_ndigit(credit, buffer, 2);
            int fst_one = fst_ndigit(credit, buffer, 1);

            if (buffer == 15 && (fst_two == 34 || fst_two == 37))
            {
                printf("AMEX\n");
            }
            else if (buffer == 16 && (fst_two == 51 || fst_two == 52 || fst_two == 53 ||
                                      fst_two == 54 || fst_two == 55))
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
            }
            else if ((buffer == 13 || buffer == 16) && fst_one == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
}

bool checksum(long int credit)
{
    int digit_count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    // checksum for the luhn algorithm
    while (credit > 0)
    {
        int digit = credit % 10;
        credit /= 10;
        digit_count++;

        if (digit_count % 2 == 0)
        {
            digit *= 2;
            if (digit > 9)
            {
                digit -= 9;
            }
        }

        sum += digit;
    }
    return (sum % 10) == 0;
}

int numofdigits(long int credit)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (credit > 0)
    {
        credit /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

bool digit(string str, int buffer)
{
    bool all_digits = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            all_digits = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return all_digits;
}

int fst_ndigit(long int credit, int buffer, int numdigit)
{
    int fstndigit = (int) (credit / (long long) pow(10, buffer - numdigit));
    return fstndigit;
}


Using integer types for credit cards numbers is only adding complexity. Use character strings instead. Using pow is introducing floating point calculations and the inherent imprecision as well. Even though the compiler is most likely doing it for you, there is zero reasons to write pow(10, 16) instead of a specific constant. Even if it is not constant, calculating integer power of 10 is trivial even with the number represented as a string.

@EugeneSh. even though i still don't understand how the complexity is reduced when i deal with the credit card number as a string, i just tried it and the same problem occurs

@abeginner1 It is highly unlikely that you had time to "try" what I am suggesting, as it is not merely types change. The reduced complexity is that when the number is represented as a string, you are getting rid of all these calculations to get individual digits. Instead you are simply indexing into the character array.

I suggest that you ignore the advice to store the credit card number as a string, for now. Although the advice is not bad, solving the assignment that way requires knowledge of arrays, which you will only learn about in week 2 of CS50. This assignment is from week 1 of CS50.

@chux do you think the pow() function is only responsible for the errors ?

@abeginner1 Perhaps, yet best to avoid FP for integer problems.

@AndreasWenzel but looking at the edit, do you think the new solution right?

@abeginner1: As far as I can tell, your second solution (the one labelled "edit") works with the numbers posted in your answer. The input "4222222222222" is found to be valid and "4111111111111113" is found to be invalid.

@abeginner1: If you want us to tell you what is wrong with your second solution, I believe you will have to post it as a complete program. As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the posted code of your second solution. I have tested it myself and it appeasrs to work.

@abeginner1 Simplify: rather than sprintf(str, "%lld", credit); ... int len = strlen(str);, use int len = sprintf(str, "%lld", credit); ...

At least these issues:
Wrong way to get least 2 significant digits
// last_two = aux % (long long) pow(10, buffer-2);
last_two = aux % 100;

Buffer overflow
sprintf(str, "%lld", credit); is UB when credit is 10,000,000,000,000,000 or larger. Instead of char str[17];, use char str[100];.
Instead of optimizing the buffer size and risking buffer overflow.  Use a generous buffer size.  I suggest 2x or more the anticipated size or write code that will absolutely not overrun.
OP's code allows credit == 10,000,000,000,000,000 which needs a buffer of 18.
Avoid floating point for an integer problem
Rework code to not use pow().
